# How to test weapons in Battlefield 3 without affecting accuracy score?

Tags: battlefield-3, battlelog

Do you know of any time when the game is [not] counting the bullets you fire or registering any hits or misses? Would the time when there is this "Waiting for players" message be suitable? The reason I ask these questions is that, as mentioned in the main question in the title, I want to be able to just change weapons, test them out with different setups, suicide the kit character, switch to a different kit or weapon, test again, and rinse and repeat. My best guess is the "Waiting for players" screen, but I'm not 100% sure that firing bullets in the air during that time really doesn't count; I hope so. Can anyone confirm this or give me a different tip to test weapons? Many thanks for anyone taking the time to offer tips or information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can play on unranked servers. On unranked servers

- all weapons may be unlocked (depending on server)
- nothing counts towards your stats
- dogtags taken still count

You should be able to test any weapon there.

Comment: In addition, servers with too few players to start the round don't count stats. Joining an empty server is a good bet.

Comment: Thank you very much. That does sound like the right solution.

Comment: But what about the individual stats for each weapon? If I fire too many bullets with a specific gun, is that going to reduce the accuracy percentage of just the weapon, even if my overall stats are unaffected?

Comment: "nothing counts towards your stats" seems to be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Not really, no. If you want to read "straightforwardly", then it says nothing counts toward _your_ stats; it did not say "your and your weapons' stats". That would be straightforward talking. My question about weapons stands.

Comment: You got me thinking, now I'm not so sure anymore. I think I'm gonna try it out and report back.

Comment: Same here; I'll see if I can do some testing. I'm asking the questions because it helps if whatever information shows up on this page is “confirmed” by more than one person.

Comment: Ok, it is surprisingly difficult to find non-passworded and non-private unranked servers or matches, but I managed to find a couple. I used only one weapon, and can confirm that whether during the "Waiting for players" screen, or after an actual short match where I fired my gun and killed one guy, and waited until the very end of the match, that gun's "Shots Fired" number did not increase at all for me after I refreshed its page. 

Weapon stats seem completely unaffected, too. But I'm just not sure if that's because of that specific server or it's all unranked ones. If more ppl can confirm...

Comment: Confirmed. When you play on a private server or during the pre-round, shots fired are not tracked.

Comment: Thank you for confirming, SSumner. I take it you mean unranked servers when you say “private”, and the reason you refer to them as private is because, indeed, most unranked servers nowadays _are_ private; however, I managed to find very few unranked servers that were luckily public. And just to clarify, when you say “during the pre-round”, are you again referring just to private/unranked servers, or are shots fired during the pre-round in _any_ server, including ranked ones, not tracked?